# Should I make a new activity/xml for each tab in my tabhost?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

Should I make a new activity/xml for each tab in my tabhost? Will this would affect performance and create a lag or will it improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Fragments instead of Activity in TabHost. The TabActivity is itself deprecated now. Check the Android Sample project for the usage. A nice tutorial on fragment - http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial